# bootstrap datetimepicker not working with control parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

First time posting, please let me know if I am missing something.

I am using [bootstrap's datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to select dates on a chart. The chart also uses a filter expression and control parameter. On initial page load, the datetimepicker widget works just fine. When i select a different radio button to change my chart data, the datetimepicker's widget no longer brings up the calendar.

I tried changing my postback to include the protected sub so when the page changes, the databind for my datetimepicker refreshes, but not luck.

ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="DTP" OnLoad="Timer1_Tick">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group date" id="StartDateCalendar">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text1" runat="server" />
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function () {
                                            $("#StartDateCalendar").datetimepicker();
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

radio buttons

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Channels_All" CellPadding="8" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="6"
    runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Timer1_Tick"  Font-Size="Small" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Total" Value="SUM" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="new" Value="new_value" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

VB

```
If IsPostBack() Then
            Timer1_Tick(sender, e)
        End If

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    DTP.DataBind()
    Sql_All.DataBind()
    Chart3.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, i found my issue is a conflict between Ajax Update Panels and bootstraps datetimepicker. This article explains and gives several ways to remedy.

https://dzone.com/articles/conflicts-between-aspnet-ajax-0

Im using method #2. Solved my issue.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id="EndDateCalendar">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="edc" runat="server" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pageLoad()
            {
                $(function () {
                    $("#StartDateCalendar").datetimepicker();
                });
                $(function () {
                    $("#EndDateCalendar").datetimepicker();
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```